# Property proxyConfig is not allowed. Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

[image: adding proxy to angular application]

When I tried to add proxy config file to angular.json showing property is not allowed.

Answer (score 8):

Try instead putting the configuration at `architect.serve.options` rather than `architect.build.options`.

https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Answer (score 3):

As it said. `proxyConfig` is not allowed inside `build.options` object. I think you meant to add it in `serve.options`. If there are no `options` then create one:

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
      },
```